# How can I import Mac Thunderbird e-mails to a Windows e-mail program?

Tags: windows, mac, email, thunderbird

My Mac laptop died. Its hard drive is still good. I was able to pull what I needed off the Mac and copy it to a Windows machine using an open source tool (I forgot its name).

I need my old e-mails. I was using Thunderbird for e-mail on the Mac. How do I load those e-mails into Thunderbird, Outlook or any other Windows e-mail tool? I did Google this, and there were some brief explanations, but they did not work. The vast majority of posts are about going from Windows to Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Find the profile folder on your Mac and copy it to proper folder on your Windows: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird

To access HFS drives from your Mac on Windows you need to use special software (i.e. MacDrive) or some Linux Live CD. (I recommend Ubuntu).